# Integral result, looking for proof or reference

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

I am looking for a proof or reference to a text which has the following result:

Let $\Omega$ be an open subset of $\mathbb{R}^{n}$. Then if $f$ is a measurable function of some sort then if it follows that for any $g \in C^{\infty}_{o}(\Omega)$ we have $$\int_{\Omega}fg dx = 0$$

then that implies that  $f = 0 \text{  almost everywhere }$.

and if $f$ is continuous and for any $g \in C^{\infty}_{o}(\Omega)$ we have $$\int_{\Omega}fg dx = 0$$ then $f = 0 \text{   everywhere}.$

Thanks for any assistance. I have seen a result like this before, I just can't recall where.

Comment: I remember seeing this in Evans PDE book Part II.

Comment: @Xiao Thanks will have a look there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are looking for a theorem of calculus of variations.
It is the du Bois-Reymond Lemma. There are other similar theorems, like a Lagrange theorem, that involves also derivatives.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Looks like the result I am looking for. Do you think I would be right in stating that $f = 0$ almost everywhere does not hold for any domain in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ if $f$ is continuous?

Comment: Well, in $\mathbb{R}$ with the Lebesgue measure, all continuous functions are measurable. Have a look here
http://mathworld.wolfram.com/MeasurableFunction.html